# Table already exists in database (only when published on Azure)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, entity-framework-migrations

Everything was working fine in my ASP.Net MVC5 EF6 project until I had database issues. The only way I found to resolve them was by deleting my database and migrations folder. I recreated everything from scratch and it fixed every issues I had locally (localhost).

Then I tried to publish my web app to Azure and now I get this error every time I try to Login in my App (first time my context is used):

> There is already an object named 'Companies' in the database.

I searched for hours on the internet about this and found nothing about this bug when it only happens when the database and web app is published (because it working perfectly fine on Debug locally).

I have read plenty of theories about migrations being messed up so I deleted my sql databse AND my Web App on my Azure portal and created new ones. Even after this, I am still getting the error.

So it seems I have an issue in my code and I know EF6 is trying to create this database table a second time but I found no places in the code where it could do that (even less where it only happens when published).  I must also tell you that nothing changed in the WebConfig and in my DbContext. Only my models changed and my Migrations folder.

I am definetly missing something here and I would really like some help to understand EF6 better. I am new to this technology and I find it very useful when it's working but when you have bug, it becomes very very painful though.

Comment: How are you pushing the database out to Azure? Migrations? Do you have AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true; ?

Comment: I am publishing to Azure using the 'Publish' feature in Visual Studio. Then I selected My WebApp site and my SQLDatabase. Been working fine since I started the project months ago. For 'AutomaticMigrationsEnabled', It was set to 'true' but I changed it to 'false' in case it was the problem and it did not change anything

Comment: Do you have migrations and have you done an update-database? Get you dev database in sync and then either copy it or change the connection string to point to Azure and rerun them. You could also script out the needed updates with Update-Database -script

Comment: I have now set 'AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true'. I updated my dev database successfully. I always publish with 'Execute Code First Migrations' checked. I just tried to publish it again and I get the same error.About copying the dev db to azure or changing the connection string to point to Azure, I don't know how to do that. I am a beginner at SQL and persistent databases in general. I don't even know how to see the data inside my AzureDb :S

Comment: See the Deploy to Azure in this link. I'm betting the database already exists and it is trying to do an update, so if you delete the database and follow the steps it might work. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: Here is what I did:  I deleted my Azure SQL Database, I modified my model slightly, did an 'update-database' and finally I added a line in the migration Configuration constructor. Still had the same issue but I observed things that might help. First, when I did a Preview of my Publish, I saw that my modification to my model and my Configuration file was not there, only my webconfig files were being published. Finally, I have a Many to Many relationship and locally I see the table that links both entities BUT this table does not exist when Published. My Seed method is also never called.